# Using Selenium to extract data provided by an autocomplete search

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to extract part of the result provided by a site's search bar's auto complete. I'm having trouble extracting the result. I'm able to enter the query I want, but I'm unable to store the autosuggestion. It seems whenever I click the drop down suggestions to "inspect element" in order to find what to select the drop down menu vanishes!

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

#launch chromedirver
driver.get("http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/ports/all")

searchBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//input[@id= "portname"]')
    )
)
searchBox.click()
searchBox.clear()
a = searchBox.send_keys('Belawan') #so far so good

selen_html = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-group').get_attribute('innerHTML')
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text=selen_html)
suggests =  hxs.select('//div[@class= "input-group"/Belawan/@title').extract
driver.close()
```

The error, unsurprisingly, is `ValueError: XPath error: Invalid predicate in //div[@....[etc]`. How do I find the correct name to put in my XPath?

The autocomplete takes the form `BELAWAN - Port [ID]` the end goal is to pull out `ID`.

Edit: 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD21r.jpg)

Comment: you can use webdriver's select class and select_by_index or select_by_value APIs to achieve your task easily.refer  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Comment: Right, but how do I find what to select?

Comment: If you can add a screenshot of which element you are trying to find then maybe I can help in a better way. write now I went to your url and entered belawan keyword but after that I'm lost.

Comment: Sorry- didn't think of it.

Comment: Saurabh baid has the answer for you, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.
Basically you will have find the xpath locators of those web elements'

In your case it was like

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 375px; left: 63px; width: 306px;">
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><b>BELA</b>WAN&nbsp;-&nbsp;Port [ID]</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-8" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><b>BELA</b>WAN ANCH&nbsp;-&nbsp;Ancorage [ID]</a></li>
</ul>
```

So I used id to get the other `ul` and then used `find_elements_by_xpath` to get list of childrend matching the xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os

#launch chromedirver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/ports/all")

searchBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//input[@id= "portname"]')
    )
)
searchBox.click()
searchBox.clear()
a = searchBox.send_keys('Belawan') #so far so good

web_elem_list = driver.find_element_by_id("ui-id-3").find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@role='presentation']/a")
suggests = [web_elem.text for web_elem in web_elem_list]
driver.close()
print suggests


# Will Give o/p
[u'BELAWAN - Port [ID]', u'BELAWAN ANCH - Ancorage [ID]']
```

Comment: @345243lkj if this solves your problem then you can accept this as answer.

Comment: I know! I did. I was testing it. One small edit I had to make was add a `time.sleep(1)` after typing into the search box, as sometimes it jumped to the next step before the autosuggest had loaded. Is there a more elegant way to fix that?

Comment: You could make use of  selenium implicit and explicit waits
Check here for more details http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: You will need to import ChromeDriverManager as well